# databaseReference vs FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I see some differences between databaseReference and FirebaseDatabase, for example: a databaseReference is used for all database operations, but i would like to know more about the main differences.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between these two classes is that [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference) represents a particular location in your database and can be used for reading or writing data, while [FirebaseDatabase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase) is the entry point for accessing the Firebase Realtime Database. You can get an instance of the class by calling the static method [getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getInstance()). To access a location in the database to read or write data, you can use [getReference()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#getReference()) method.

Answer (score 0):

As Firebase documentation says:

> A Firebase reference represents a particular location in your Database
>   and can be used for reading or writing data to that Database location.
>
> This class is the starting point for all Database operations. After
>   you've initialized it with a URL, you can use it to read data, write
>   data, and to create new DatabaseReferences.

and Firebase database is:

> The entry point for accessing a Firebase Database. You can get an
>   instance by calling getInstance(). To access a location in the
>   database and read or write data, use getReference()